# Can a G Suite admin see every email that comes through their organization?

Tags: smtp, gmail, hosting, google-workspace

I would like to know if anyone has experience as a G Suite admin, and if so, how easy is it for the super admin to access all emails coming through their organization? Particularly if a business owner has suspicions about an employee sending/receiving emails that are not aligned with the company's values and ethics.

Thank you - the Google literature is dense I would like to have a full understanding before spending money.

Comment: as the name suggests that super admin can access all the users under the super admin, now you can understand that SA  can read other users' emails, etc. Yes, admin can see every email that comes through their organization

Comment: Thank you. It's much easier to set things up correctly up front instead of changing things after creation!

Comment: you are welcome! yes its easy to set up things